# Do weaknesses add to flag-buff damage?

Tags: battlecry

In [BattleCry](http://www.kongregate.com/games/BerzerkStudio/battlecry), a unit with -x resistance toward a damage type will take x extra damage from that damage type. A unit with a flag will add 1 damage of a particular type to the attacks of all units in the squad. Will a unit who gains a damage of the type the enemy is weak against benefit from the enemy's weakness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand the game a bit better, I've been able to test the question. Act 2 Mission 4, "Steam Powered Behemoth" has a [steam behemoth](http://battle-cry.wikia.com/wiki/Steam_Behemoth) which has -10 bolt resistance. I decided to test a unit of archers with a flag the behemoth is not weak against ([viper flag](http://battle-cry.wikia.com/wiki/Viper_Flag)) and with a flag the behemoth is weak against ([Bolt Flag](http://battle-cry.wikia.com/wiki/Bolt_Flag)).

---

### **Control Army (viper flag)**

**Setup:**
[image]
The front line of [vermin](http://battle-cry.wikia.com/wiki/Vermin) has no defenses and two-handed hammers. They wipe out the enemy's front line while simultaneously being wiped out. The midsection of armored [humans](http://battle-cry.wikia.com/wiki/Human) has armor but no weapons. They slow the [steam behemoth](http://battle-cry.wikia.com/wiki/Steam_Behemoth) down without damaging it to give the archers time to shoot at it. The rear section has archers with [short bows](http://battle-cry.wikia.com/wiki/Short_Bow) and a [viper-flag](http://battle-cry.wikia.com/wiki/Viper_Flag) bearer. With the viper-flag bearer, the archers each deal 2 piercing damage and 1 poison damage with each shot.

**Results:**
[image]
The behemoth is able to wipe out all of the midsection before succumbing to the archers.

---

### Experimental Army (bolt flag)

**Setup:**
[image]
Setup is the same as the control, but the flag bearer now has a [Bolt Flag](http://battle-cry.wikia.com/wiki/Bolt_Flag). Now the archers deal 2 piercing damage and 1 bolt damage per shot.

**Results:**
[image]
The behemoth is only able to defeat the first 3 armored humans before succumbing to the archers.

---

### Conclusion

Flag-buff damage does indeed benefit from enemy weakness of the same element.